# God using sudo fails to find the environment parameter SECRET_KEY_BASE in the .bash_profile file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, bash, god

I added those rows to `/home/web/.bash_profile`. The web is the user of Rails app.

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
export SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

I added this row into `/etc/sudoers`.

```
Defaults env_keep += "SECRET_KEY_BASE"
```

This command returns expected result.

```
sudo ruby -e 'puts ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]'
```

If I run Unicorn without God, it can find SECRET_KEY_BASE from environment, and performs normally.

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

Running Unicorn using sudo without God performs normally, too.

```
sudo bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

But when I run Unicorn with God using sudo, it failed to find SECRET_KEY_BASE and becomes error.

```
sudo god start my_app
```

The start command in the my_app.god is this.

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.start = "cd #{rails_root} && bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E #{rails_env} -D"
  w.uid = 'web'
  w.gid = 'web'
...
end
```

It seems that the problem exists around God rather than .bash_profile and Unicorn. Besides what should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line into the `my_app.god`

```
ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

I know that this isn't a cool solution, but it works. And SECRET_KEY_BASE isn't included in a Git repository as source code.